# How would you mavenize the Apache Flex SDK 4.13?

Tags: maven, apache-flex, air

I read the manual available here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/Apache+Flex+SDK+Mavenizer. But it's confusing me. It's told that I should apply converter seprately to Flex SDK and Air SDK. But at present both of SDKs downloaded and merged by current Apache Flex Installer (should I download packages manually?). Also I don't have the flex-sdk-converter-1.0.jar. After build the mavenizer I have air-converter-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, flex-converter-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, base-converter-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar and flash-converter-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.

How to use those tools to properly put Flex and Air SDK to the maven repositoy?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem 2 months back.
The documentation on the website was for older version.
It has been updated on November 03rd.
Can you try again by following that?

Comment: Hi, yes It has been updated after I made this post http://apache-flex-users.2333346.n4.nabble.com/Mavenize-Apache-Flex-SDK-4-13-in-couple-with-Air-15-td8549.html. I've resolved this issue, but now I 've got new). Updating either flash player or flex sdk sometimes is really painful.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the current documented process now.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/Preparing+FDKs+for+Maven+builds